# Which classes should implements Serializable in JSF appl?

Tags: java, jsf, serialization, jsf-2

Which classes should `implements Serializable` in JSF application and which not?

- `@SessionScoped @ManagedBean()`
- `@ViewScoped @ManagedBean()` (all my views are viewscoped)
- `@ApplicationScoped`
- `@Entity @Table()`
- `Servlets`
- `Filters`
- etc.

How should I think about it, what to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. The first thing you need to answer is whether you want to use session serialization or not. If you need serialization, then everything in session needs to be serializable. Otherwise you don't need it at all. Serialization is used to persist sessions upon server restart or seldom - in really complex setups - to transfer them to another server instance.

Some containers will require you to explicitly disable session serialization or else they will be generating exceptions. For instance, tomcat by default enables persisting session through server restart.